# Should I be adding as many examples as possible to a documentation topic?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I noticed there's an example which seems out of place on documentation but it's clearly getting up voted. Let's imagine the topic was *C hello world*

I'm just guessing but I think most programmers? would expect to see something alone the lines of

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(...) {
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

And of course that example is there. Please don't get lost in minutia of that example. It's not the point of this discussion

So, after that someone else is like "Well maybe you want send hello world through a socket" so they provide a *hello world* that uses sockets.

My stupid traditional self thinks it's a great example but it doesn't belong in under "c hello world" it belongs under c sockets. And yet, the example is getting upvoted and upvoted.

So, the question. Should I give in to the crowd and add "hello world" examples in every way possible? How to write "c hello world" to a file. How to open a window in OpenGL and and display "hello world". How to make an iOS C app that says "hello world". All under the topic of "C Hello World"?

Given it's getting voted up it appears that's what people want.

I left a downvote (maybe the wrong thing) and explained that while the example was great it seemed like it belonged under "C sockets" instead of "C hello world". Should I leave it at that and keep hoping things go the way I selfishly want or should I go for what people are voting for and just add every possible way I can think of to display "hello world" from C?

Or is there something else I should do?

PS: The topic is *not* C

### Update

I see there is a `move example` button but nothing happens when I click it.

[image: move example]

I guess it's coming soon? Or I don't have permission to use it.

Comment: _"a great example but it doesn't belong in under "c hello world""_ I agree. We don't want a bazillion examples of how you _could_ do it. For this example, the the example code should be in a "Hello world" example under "C-> Sockets". I'd reject examples like that as "Too specific".

Comment: Fully agree. Why do you do a "hello world" ? Basically its a test - your first baby step into doing "something". The generic hello world posted as an example would be the first test you do to compile, link and run a C program. An example for sending hello world over a socket makes little sense to be posted right next to it, conceptually and technologically it is miles away from it.

Comment: "It seems that perfection is attained, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing more to take away." (Exupéry) - so no. Don't add as many examples as possible.

Comment: Perhaps a better version of the question would be "what incentives or rules exist to limit excessive examples?". I know they said they were going to add a target number of examples per topic. Perhaps the only other check in place is simple downvoting.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing a hello world example of opening something in openGL and writing to it :) I don't see why we should worry about example counts. Questions reached 10,000,000 and we all got swag. Shouldn't we aspire to get there with examples so we also get more swag? I think yes.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation), the answer is likely no:

> #### Keep example counts manageable
>
> The typical topic has between one and six examples, and the typical example has a paragraph of explanation and some code. As topics grow, consider splitting them and moving examples to new topics.

Of course, it's best to decide on a case-by-case basis. Sometimes too many examples (like one for sort ascending, and another for sort descending) is a sign that both examples need to be combined into one example that broadly covers both topics (which likely only differ by a single line of code or less).